# angular 5 & 8 - 431 Request Header Fields Too Large

Tags: http-headers, angular5, angular8

I'm working on 2 projects and installed Angular 8 in my machine for new project. But, I'm using Angular 5 for existing project. I'm getting **431 Request Header Fields Too Large** error in my Angular5 project after I installed Angular 8. How can I fix this error in my current project?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

To add to Murilo's answer, you can clear the guilty cookie in chrome by:

1. hitting F12 (to open developer tools)
2. in the application tab expand cookies, right click the localhost url.
3. click clear.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I've had the same problem and it looks like that is a browser cache issue. Try to open your application in an incognito windows or clean your cache, i did it and it worked

Comment: The incognito option has worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem, after checked i found content of HttpHeaders too large